# Live Activities is not working with custom colours

Tags: swiftui, widgetkit

When I try to use custom colours in Live Activities, the activity in the Lock Screen is not appear at all.

In the code, I use an extension to conform Color to Codable, otherwise is not compile. (I found the Color extension [here](https://gist.github.com/peterfriese/bb2fc5df202f6a15cc807bd87ff15193))

```
struct MeetingTimerAttributes: ActivityAttributes {
    public typealias TimeTrackingStatus = ContentState
    
    public struct ContentState: Codable, Hashable {
        var elapsedTime: Int
        var remainingTime: Int
        var meetingDuration: Double
        var mainColor: Color
    }
}

extension Color: Codable {

  // Full code in the link

}
```

And here is the Live Activity view:

```
struct TimeTrackingWidgetView: View {
    let context: ActivityViewContext<MeetingTimerAttributes>
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Total Time: \(Int(context.state.meetingDuration)) minutes")
                .padding(.top, 10)
                .bold()
            
            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Minutes Elapsed")
                        .font(.caption)
                    
                    Label("\(context.state.elapsedTime.secondsToMinutes())", systemImage: "hourglass.bottomhalf.fill")
                }
                Spacer()
                VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                    Text("Minutes Remaining")
                        .font(.caption)
                    Label("\(context.state.remainingTime.secondsToMinutes())", systemImage: "hourglass.tophalf.fill")
                        .labelStyle(.titleAndIcon)
                }
            }
            .padding(.init(top: 5, leading: 15, bottom: 10, trailing: 15))
        }
        .background(context.state.mainColor) <---- This line
    }
}
```

If I use .background(context.state.mainColor) the Live activity is not appear but if I use background(.red), for example, it works just fine.

The color are sRGB created in the assets catalog, like this one:
[image]

Any idea?

Comment: What color are you actually trying to use? That Codable extension may not work for some colors, such as grays.

Comment: The color is sRGB created in the assets catalog. I edit the main post with an image and this information about the colours.

Comment: Could you try calling your Codable conformance yourself? I mean let the `ContentState` have a `mainColor` of type `Data` which you get by encoding the color via a `JSONEncoder`. When accessing the color in SwiftUI decode the data back to a `Color`. This might not solve your problem but may hint at a bug that `ContentState` doesn't allow custom `Codable` conformances? If the color is in your asset catalog you could also just set the color's name in your `ContentState`.